# Retrieve vimeo video information from xml

Tags: php, xml, vimeo

I want to get data from XML API output from Vimeo.

In Vimeo if we load this URL:  `http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/30055721.xml` the video ID is `30055721`, it will output the XML data in the browser (single-line XML chunk):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><videos><video><id>30055721</id><title>[MV]I-ny(아이니) 뮤직비디오</title><description>눈부신 가을 하늘을 닮은 목소리의 주인공 '아이니(i-ny)',  &lt;br /&gt;  그녀의 이름을 노래하다.</description><url>http://vimeo.com/30055721</url><upload_date>2011-10-04 22:34:19</upload_date><mobile_url>http://vimeo.com/m/30055721</mobile_url><thumbnail_small>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/201/671/201671639_100.jpg</thumbnail_small><thumbnail_medium>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/201/671/201671639_200.jpg</thumbnail_medium><thumbnail_large>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/201/671/201671639_640.jpg</thumbnail_large><user_id>2991448</user_id><user_name>Deviljoon</user_name><user_url>http://vimeo.com/user2991448</user_url><user_portrait_small>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/217/387/2173872_30.jpg</user_portrait_small><user_portrait_medium>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/217/387/2173872_75.jpg</user_portrait_medium><user_portrait_large>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/217/387/2173872_100.jpg</user_portrait_large><user_portrait_huge>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/217/387/2173872_300.jpg</user_portrait_huge><stats_number_of_likes>3</stats_number_of_likes><stats_number_of_plays>542</stats_number_of_plays><stats_number_of_comments>0</stats_number_of_comments><duration>235</duration><width>1280</width><height>720</height><tags>I-ny, 아이니, 뮤직비디오, music video, MV, kpop, k-pop, 550d</tags><embed_privacy>anywhere</embed_privacy></video></videos>
```

But I want to retrieve data in the XML field dynamically to show it in my webpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this article for a complete run through:

http://ditio.net/2008/06/19/using-php-curl-to-read-rss-feed-xml/

This should give you a good idea about how to fetch the XML contents into your PHP script, then parse the contents of the XML into your PHP. You will need to make some adaptations to the process of parsing the feed, specific to the vimeo output, but you should be able to do this simply by having a play.

e.g. the below will output the ID.

```
$ch = curl_init("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/30055728.xml");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$xml= new SimpleXmlElement($data, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
echo "<strong>".$xml->video->id."</strong>";
```

Once `$xml` has been established, simply change `$xml->video->id` to whichever node you want (crucually the 'id' section').

Comment: It worked, thanks, I am just going through the code with my tweaks to it

Comment: hmmm not sure why- works absolutely a-OK when tested, testing with the latest version of PHP on a live host

Comment: See here, there seems to be an issue when using CRUL with WAMP: http://www.wampserver.com/phorum/read.php?2,43026,43027. It works on live deployments however.

Comment: it worked, I used the first code you given here, eventually I notice that you edited that code, thanks